# Python requests how to configure SSL?

Tags: python, ubuntu, ssl, urllib

I'm trying to download a file with requests

```
http_response = requests.get(url)
```

And I keep getting this error

```
SSLError(1, '[SSL: DH_KEY_TOO_SMALL] dh key too small (_ssl.c:1131)'))
```

Stack says it's a configuration issue with the library and suggests configuring it however I haven't found any solutions that end up working.

Any suggestions on fixing this error? (code was working 2 months ago when I last ran)

Answer (score -1):

To get around this problem, the nuclear option is to pass  `verify=False` as part of your requests call:

```
http_response = requests.get(url, verify=False)
```

This turns off all verification of SSL certificates.

Comment: DH_KEY_TOO_SMALL has nothing to do with certificates